# What is the error :a conflict exists with inherited definition flash.display:DisplayObject.mouseX in namespace public?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

This appeared as I was trying to use a mouseEvent to move an  object.
I placed the variables for mouseX and mouseY in the public class. I did the same for direction X and Y but there was no error message for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class you are adding the `mouseX` to is extending the `DisplayObject` type (and if it's any kind of Flex component than it does), you already have a variable with that name from that type. As a fix name your variable something else eg. `myMouseX`. If you don't know what exactly I'm taking about with extending classes, check the tutorial on [Object-oriented programming in ActionScript](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_01.html).